# Image display small in lollipop 5.0

Tags: android

I am showing **Bitmap Image** in my code through **URL**. Image appears with correct size in other devices but appears **too small** in lollipop version.

How can i solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
try {
            String imageUrl=params[0];
            url = new URL(AppConstants.BASE_URL+"Images/"+imageUrl);
            bm = ImageThreadLoader.readBitmapFromNetwork(url);
            bitmap_new = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);       
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap_new);
            final int color = 0xff424242;
            final Paint paint = new Paint();
            final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
            final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
            final float roundPx = 17.0f;
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bm, rect, rect, paint);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: put screenshot or code for people understanding your problem

Comment: Image look as i want in all other devices except Devices having lollipop version

Comment: maybe resolution of lollipop device is higher

Answer (score 0):

Your, lollipop device should have an higher resolution if you can find the resolution 

link - [Android Changing image size depending on Screen Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798355/android-changing-image-size-depending-on-screen-size)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `ImageView` with some image loader library?
For example [`Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Just set your `ImageView` to the size which you want:

In your layout file:

```
...
   <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:scaleType="centerInside"
     />
...
```

And in your activity/ fragment:

```
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ...
    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
    Picasso.with(this).load("https://your/image/location.jpg").into(myImageView);
    ...
}

...
```

This will ensure that your image will scale according to the pixel density of the device.