# How can i change an ImageVIew programmatically according to screensize in android app?

Tags: android, imageview

My question states that, my image should should adjust according to 5 inch screen and 5.5 inch screen accordingly.

Comment: Similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798355/android-changing-image-size-depending-on-screen-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `width` and `height` of display screen at runtime.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Now you can set width and height of your `imageview` according to screen width and height like

```
image_view.getLayoutParams().height = height/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add image(With diff size) in all related layout folders and just change image in program.

For ex: assume image name is `image1.png`(With diff size).

Add the images in `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1.png);
```

Will do the trick.

For more refer http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Also you can have different layout for different screen sizes, by defining xml with same name in all related layout folders. ex: `layout-hdpi`, `layout-xhdpi`.

Comment: thanks thats helpful