# Dynamically increase the size of custom marker in google maps - Android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, picasso

I use Picasso to retrieve the Bitmap image to use as a marker icon and it apply successfully. But I need to dynamically increase the size of the custom marker for all devices. Because with my code below, it's working fine in some devices but in some others devices, the marker is very big.

Here's my code

```
dest = new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude());
markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(dest);
location_marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
Target target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);
targets.add(target);

Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(84, 125).into(target);
mMarkersHashMap.put(location_marker, myMarker);
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any solution? any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the code you provided, you can just modify the value you passed in the `resize()` in this line:

```
Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(84, 125).into(target);
```

I tried it out, your code shows this:

[image]

Then I modified the value of in the `resize()`, like so:

```
Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(184, 1125).into(target);
```

And it turned out like this:

[image]

The value to pass in `resize()` all depends on you. ;)

> **EDIT**

If your concern is on **what** value to pass depending on the screen size, You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4798597/4625829) from a different post. Here's what it says --

You can do this with `LayoutParams` in code. Unfortunately there's no way to specify percentages through XML (not directly, you can mess around with weights, but that's not always going to help, and it won't keep your aspect ratio), but this should work for you:

```
//assuming your layout is in a LinearLayout as its root
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);

ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

int newHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() / 2;
int orgWidth = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int orgHeight = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

//double check my math, this should be right, though
int newWidth = Math.floor((orgWidth * newHeight) / orgHeight);

//Use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams if your parent is a RelativeLayout
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    newWidth, newHeight);
image.setLayoutParams(params);
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
layout.addView(image);
```

-- It's quite a good example, simply measure the layout to use it as reference on how you will size the image.

Comment: Yeah, i use `resize(84, 125)` and it runs well in some device. But i tried in some others devices, the markers are very big. But I need to dynamically increase the size of the custom marker for all devices. So when running this app, the markers will adjust the device's screen. What should i do?

Comment: You should think of the formula that will provide the values you are looking for, where the width and height depends on the screen size.. I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4798597/4625829) might work for you. :)